# Flatbuffers converting json to binary - unexpected force_align value

Tags: flatbuffers

I convert a binary file to json with the following command with flatbuffers.

```
flatc --json  schema.fbs -- model.blob
```

When I try to immediately convert the json back to a binary with this command

```
flatc -b schema.fbs model.json
```

It throws an error

```
error: unexpected force_align value '64', alignment must be a power of two integer ranging from the type's natural alignment 1 to 16
```

It points to the very last line of the json file as the problem. Does anybody know the problem? Could it be escape sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `force_align: 64` somewhere in `schema.fbs` ? That would be the real source of the problem. It ignores this attribute when generating the JSON, but i

Comment: yes there is `force_align: 64` in the schema. So I guess that is the source of the error. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Well, you'd have to find out why the author of the schema put that there. It is likely safe to replace with `16`, unless the schema is for something highly specific hardware related feature.